# PowerBI Dynamic Columns slicers

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have tabular powerBI reports where few columns gets populated dynamically ( Like Year2022 , Year2023 ) within source query.

Report looks something like attache image.

Now Business Require slicer/Filter in such a way that He can filter those dynamic columns and he gets control to show and hide columns based on slicer selection with report.

I have find the solution but that is more suitable for filtering Static Columns , Is there any way we can filters Dynamic Columns through slicers .

Since Dynamic Columns numbers not fixed sometime ,

For one data refresh i can see Year2022, Year2023 and for other Year2025  ,Year2026.

Any solutions, direction will be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A2Wk.jpg)

Comment: Typically you would unpivot the year columns, but this doesn’t work when you have different data types ( Data, Date) in them.

Comment: Correct , Also if you Unpivot Columns then required visual would be Matrix not table .